# Pander error with lrm function in rms package

Tags: r, pander

I am trying to use pander to render a model created by the lrm function in the rms package, but I get an error

```
     lg<-lrm(Y~v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6, data=temp)
     pander(lg)
```

The error that I get is:

```
Error: 'reVector' is not an exported object from 'namespace:rms'
```

Here is my sessionInfo:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] pander_0.6.0    rms_5.1-1       SparseM_1.77    Hmisc_4.0-3     ggplot2_2.2.1   Formula_1.2-1   survival_2.41-3 lattice_0.20-35
```

The pander documentation indicates that rms functions are supported. Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, the `pander.lrm` method relies on a bunch of internal `rms` stuff, changes in the `rms` package broke this method a couple of times already -- the most recent fix is not yet commited yet I think. It's also possible that because of these issues, we might drop `rms` support in the future, as it's hard to follow all supported packages' changes -- although we might PR to the upstream packages.

Comment: Ok, thanks very much for the quick reply!

Comment: Actually, I think this was fixed after all at https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/issues/283

Comment: So I should not be getting this error?

Comment: That's right. Please check the most recent version of `pander` from GH or CRAN (although that latter just got updated, it might take a couple days to distribute).